# How to convert a list with multiple dict to a dict

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Trying to convert below list of dict to dict as below:

```
mylist=[{'A1': 'AAA', 'B1': '0.0000300'}, {'A1': 'BBB', 'B1': '0.0164500'}, {'A1': 'CCC', 'B1': '0.00179350'}
```

And below dict output is what I am looking for:

```
neededdict={'AAA': '0.0000300', 'BBB': '0.0164500', 'CCC': '0.00179350'}
```

but should not be as below:

```
notneeded={'A1': 'AAA', 'B1':'0.0000300','A1': 'BBB', 'B1': '0.0164500','A1': 'CCC', 'B1': '0.00179350'}
```

How to solve this problem ?

Comment: please show us what you have tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `dict()`

**Demo:**

```
mylist=[{'A1': 'AAA', 'B1': '0.0000300'}, {'A1': 'BBB', 'B1': '0.0164500'}, {'A1': 'CCC', 'B1': '0.00179350'}]
print( dict((i["A1"], i["B1"]) for i in mylist))
```

**Output:**

```
{'AAA': '0.0000300', 'BBB': '0.0164500', 'CCC': '0.00179350'}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this simple [dictionary comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34835952/6671176):

```
{i['A1']: i['B1'] for i in mylist}
# {'AAA': '0.0000300', 'BBB': '0.0164500', 'CCC': '0.00179350'}
```